# Why I am getting zeros in both loss and accuracy in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Getting ***Zeros*** for both **Accuracy and loss** while building a tensorflow model for a classification problem.

I have posted a sample epoch here:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100,input_dim=X_train.shape[1],activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'],
                                              optimizer='rmsprop')
model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=5,verbose=1)
```

```
Epoch 2/5
33/33 [==============================] - 1s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

[image]

Comment: can you show y_train.shape

Comment: # y_train.shape=(1043,) and X_train.shape is (1043, 22195)

Comment: @Netim Thank you, I tried but no change at all

Comment: The problem might be coming from the activation function of the last layer you are using. AS Softmax ouput probability, so either switch to sigmoid and binary_crossentropy as loss, or modify your output shape to 2, you will need to modify you y_true shape if you decide to use a Dense layer of size 2 for prediction(i deleted my last comment as i miss read your code)

Comment: Thank you @Netim,, but its not working with binary_crossentropy  and sigmoid ..
and I have to classify 4 values ,,so i've used softmax

Comment: Oh so here is you problem, you have 4 classes and your last layer is of size 1, keep the softmax and switch the size of your last layer to 4 and tell us how it goes

Comment: ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 4) are incompatible ,,,,got this error

Comment: You need to modify your y_train to one hot encoding to be of shape (1043,4), I suppose that your labels are currently number between 0 and 3.

Comment: y.replace(to_replace{'business':0,'tech':2,'politics':3,'entertainment':4,'sport':5},inplace=True)
I performed this..@Netim

Comment: yes that's what i'm saying, encode 0 => [1,0,0,0, 0], 2 => [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 3 => [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 4 => [0, 0, 0, 1, 0] ,  5 => [0, 0, 0, 0, 1] (i supposed you skip 1 on purpose) The best would be to use directly one hot encoding from keras https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-perform-one-hot-encoding-using-keras

Comment: @Netim array([[3.91234457e-01, 3.96843821e-01, 3.91917937e-02, 3.77120264e-02,
        1.35017902e-01],
       [1.50013832e-07, 4.60932540e-07, 9.99999404e-01, 1.93847320e-08,
        4.24148688e-10],
       [1.34745468e-08, 1.16067994e-07, 9.99999881e-01, 1.64661831e-08,
        3.86613380e-11],.....
      .
Getting error like this after using one hot encoding, loss and accuracies were fixed but while evaluation I'am getting this ..... i.e., model.predict(X_test)

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

1. Check the number of unique values of Y. That is your number of target classes. From what I understood you have 4 unique classes. Now you will set the number of unique classes as the units in the last output layer along with `softmax` activation as the problem is multi-class and not multi-label.

```
model.add(Dense(4,activation='softmax'))
```

2. Now if you have your Y in shape ( _ , ) then it means that Y is a vector and each class is represented by a integer and hence is sparse. In such cases you change your loss to `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` after which this will be the final code.

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100,input_dim=X_train.shape[1],activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
               metrics=['accuracy'],
              optimizer='rmsprop')

model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=5,verbose=1)
```

Comment: array([[3.91234457e-01, 3.96843821e-01, 3.91917937e-02, 3.77120264e-02, 1.35017902e-01], [1.50013832e-07, 4.60932540e-07, 9.99999404e-01, 1.93847320e-08, 4.24148688e-10], [1.34745468e-08, 1.16067994e-07, 9.99999881e-01, 1.64661831e-08, 3.86613380e-11],..... . Getting error like this after using one hot encoding, loss and accuracies were fixed but while evaluation I'am getting this ..... i.e., model.predict(X_test)

Comment: @seerammoui These are not error but probabilities. for the first example i.e. `[3.91234457e-01, 3.96843821e-01, 3.91917937e-02, 3.77120264e-02, 1.35017902e-01]` this is roughly equal to `[0.391, 0.396, 0.039, 0.037, 0.135]`. This says that the probability of the prediction belong to 0th class is 0.39, 1st class is 0.39, 2nd class is 0.039, 3rd is 0.037 and 4th is 0.135.